# recieving HTTP POST echo response from a PHP file (sending the POSTS works fine, it's the receive that I can't figure out)

Tags: java, php, android, http-post, echo

So as the title suggest my problem is getting a response to a HTTP POST I'm making. 
What SHOULD be happening is I send a bunch of variables, the PHP checks the database for them and sends back to me the result (as an echo to the page).

Here is the android code:

```
 public class CheckChallenge extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
  {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) 
    {
      String response = "";
      try
      {
        URL = urls[0];
   ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("victim",NetPlay.myId)); 
   // need to return these to an array
   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rival",rivalid));


        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("word","null"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("won","0"));

          HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
          HttpPost httppost = new      
          HttpPost("http://www.hanged.comli.com/check-rival.php");
          httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

          HttpResponse execute = httpclient.execute(httppost);
          HttpEntity entity = execute.getEntity();

          //InputStream is = entity.getContent();

          //mText.setText(is.toString());

         Log.i("postData", execute.getStatusLine().toString());
         //HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
              Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
      }
            return response;
        } 

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {
        // CHECK ENTIRE DATABASE FOR MY ID //
        // IF MY ID IS THERE THEN THAT MEANS IVE CHALLENGED SOMEONE //


    }

  }
```

Here is the PHP which I think is ok just including this for completeness:
     $connect = mysql_connect("$mysql_host", "$mysql_user", "$mysql_password")or   die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$mysql_database", $connect)or die("cannot select DB");
    session_start();

```
$victim = $_POST['victim'];
$rival = $_POST['rival'];
$word = $_POST['word'];
$won = $_POST['won'];

$query = "SELECT rival FROM currentgames";
$result = mysql_query($query);

 if (!$result) 
 {
echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) 
{
echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
exit;
}

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
 echo $row["rival"];
}
```

Any help with this would be very appreciated, trying to get my head around all this HTTP POSTing stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example of sending an HTTP request and reading back the HTTP response:

```
String res = "";
String url = "http://www.domain.com/youscript.php";
URL urlObj = new URL(url);
URLConnection lu = urlObj.openConnection();


// Send data - if you don't need to send data 
// ignore this section and just move on to the next one
String data = URLEncoder.encode("yourdata", "UTF-8");
lu.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(lu.getOutputStream());
wr.write(data);
wr.flush();

// Get the response
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(lu.getInputStream()));
String line = "", res = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
  res += line;
}

wr.flush();
wr.close();
System.out.println(res);
```

Comment: So to incorporate this into how I'm already doing it, I can just use a buffered reader on the InputStream I have already and that would work?

Comment: @RaidenXL yes. it worked for me on my app. I believe that you can use the `getEntity()` option too, but I don't have any experience with it so I can't help you with that.