# Android : Confused/Lost with Call a PHP webservice with Send & Receive

Tags: php, android, web-services

From my android app, I want to call php web services. At times, I just need some data from php, sometime get data based on some parameter passed. I prefer to use RAW Api like HttpClient. I also plan to use mySql DB.

To call php web services, I got references from http://lukencode.com/2010/04/27/calling-web-services-in-android-using-httpclient/, and http://www.anddev.org/doing_http_post_with_android-t492.html, http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

I am STUCK at : 
For eg: I pass 2 parameters with my url "http://......php?src=SOURCE&dest=DEST
REsult - Directions from SOURCE to DEST (at times result may be an array of strings, items, etc)

1. How to do send & receive data back in single request ?
2. How to write php for the same ?
3. Can the above accomplished using raw aPI or JSon or ksoap is required ? I have read that instead of using Jsoan or Soap, raw is the best approach.

Kindly help me to solve the confusion and proceed ahead wit hthe application.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I just replayed [*the same question*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11963353/1057429) yesterday :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [recieving HTTP POST echo response from a PHP file (sending the POSTS works fine, it's the receive that I can't figure out)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963190/recieving-http-post-echo-response-from-a-php-file-sending-the-posts-works-fine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,

alfasin, thru ur post and other sites I got things properly working.